# Emscripten FS when emitting ES6 mjs

Tags: webassembly, emscripten

When I compile with `emcc --bind -lworkerfs.js -o pmread.js pmread.cpp -s WASM=1 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1` The program works fine,

But if I emit ES6 module using `emcc --bind -lworkerfs.js -o pmread.mjs pmread.cpp -s WASM=1 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1` Since the mjs only has default export on `Module` FS is not available. How do I use Emscripten's File System FS when emitting ES& module?

I have tried changing to Named export in pmread.mjs and `export {Module, FS}` But the Web Worker refuse to load
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved by emitting pmread.js and append export  {Module,FS,WORKERFS} at the end